# How do I put hint in a asp:textbox

Tags: asp.net, css, html, placeholder, hint

How do I put a hint/placeholder inside a asp:TextBox?  When I say a hint I mean some text which disappears when the user clicks on it. Is there a way to achieve the same using html / css?

Comment: Which browsers are you supporting? HTML5 browsers support the `placeholder` attribute for textboxes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501114/in-asp-net-unable-to-save-textboxes-if-the-text-is-given-in-between-and

Answer (score 239, accepted):

## The `placeholder` attribute

You're looking for the [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#The_placeholder_attribute) attribute. Use it like any other attribute inside your ASP.net control:

```
<asp:textbox id="txtWithHint" placeholder="hint" runat="server"/>
```

Don't bother about your IDE (i.e. Visual Studio) maybe **not knowing** the attribute. Attributes which are not registered with ASP.net are passed through and rendered as is. So the above code (basically) renders to:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="hint"/>
```

## Using `placeholder` in resources

A fine way of applying the hint to the control is using [resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). This way you may have localized hints. Let's say you have an *index.aspx* file, your *App_LocalResources/index.aspx.resx* file contains

```
<data name="WithHint.placeholder">
    <value>hint</value>
</data>
```

and your control looks like

```
<asp:textbox id="txtWithHint" meta:resourcekey="WithHint" runat="server"/>
```

the rendered result will look the same as the one in the chapter above.

## Add attribute in code behind

Like any other attribute you can add the `placeholder` to the [`AttributeCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.attributecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
txtWithHint.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "hint");
```

Comment: For some reason the resource trick `"WithHint.placeholder"` didn't work for me.

Comment: When using resources, you can do this for a local resource file: `<asp:TextBox ID="txtWithHint" runat="server" placeholder="<%$ Resources: 52 %>" />` or for global resources: `<asp:TextBox ID="txtWithHint" runat="server" placeholder="<%$ Resources: ResourceFile, ResourceValue %>" />`

Comment: when adding a control in code, all you apparently need is: myTextBox.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "hint");

Answer (score 61):

Just write like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" placeholder="hi test"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 19):

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPassword" placeholder="Password">
```

This will work you might some time feel that it is not working due to Intellisence not showing **placeholder**

Answer (score 8):

Adding placeholder attributes from code-behind:

```
txtFilterTerm.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Filter" + Filter.Name);
```

Or

```
txtFilterTerm.Attributes["placeholder"] = "Filter" + Filter.Name;
```

Adding placeholder attributes from aspx Page

```
<asp:TextBox type="text" runat="server" id="txtFilterTerm" placeholder="Filter" />
```

Or

```
<input type="text" id="txtFilterTerm" placeholder="Filter"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
asp:TextBox ID="txtName" placeholder="any text here"
```