# Placeholder/Example text in textbox for user

Tags: asp.net, textbox

What is the step to get example text to show up in an **asp.net textbox**.

For example, textbox w/ ID =  `"textboxDate"` has `[mm/dd/yyyy]` inside it for the user to reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I put hint in a asp:textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823983/how-do-i-put-hint-in-a-asptextbox)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I believe you want a `placeholder` attribute:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="placeholderTextBox" runat="server" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I have a question. Please answer. I used this `attribute` for `TextBox` but Visual Studio said : `Attribute 'placeholder' is not a valid attribute of element 'TextBox'`

But program worked fine , I could get result what I wanted.

Can this message be cause any problem ?

Comment: @Jeyhun, don't worry about that warning message.

Comment: @Jeyhun, the message is merely an annoyance. It can be avoided by setting the placeholder in the Code Behind like `placeholderTextBox.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "mm/dd/yyyy")`. Putting it in the Code Behind is kind of annoying too, but at least the message stops. (This is true for Visual Studio 2015 and possibly other versions.)

Answer (score 6):

but placeholder doenst work for many IE browser because placeholder is html5 thing.

try to use modernizr framework. it works for all browsers including all IE

here is a sample code for you.

```
if(modernizr.input.placeholder) {
   //insert placeholder polyfill script here. 
}
```

Comment: I was only going to tell that this isn't working in IE and I saw your post - thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio maybe not knowing the attribute. Attributes which are not registered with ASP.net are passed through and rendered as is.

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  Width="187px" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"></asp:TextBox>
```

So the above code (basically) renders to:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can allways use:

```
<input ID="placeholderTextBox" type="text" runat="server" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" />
```

and on code behind you can get or set the value using

```
Dim myValue As String = placeholderTextBox.value or placeholderTextBox.value = "whatsoever"
```