# Display hint for text inside asp's textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm looking for ways to display some text for the user within an `<asp:textbox>` that can help him know what data/format of text he should enter in each textbox. It's looks like this (Sample from Facebook Sign up page) :

[image]

My only solution now is to

1- set the default text for the textbox in the aspx
2- Set its color to grey
3- Onclick of the textbox : 
   1- Change color to black
4- Onchange, if text is empty set the text back to default

This sounds like i'm developing in the 90s, is there an out-of-the-box property for the textbox to do this, or any more intelligent way to do it ?

**Happy New Year**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to theonlygusti and J.Wells answer, I got to know what a "placeholder" is. And thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689890/add-html5-placeholder-text-to-a-textbox-net) post, I was able to make use of it in my textbox

This answer better serves my purpose as i do not have to change my Textbox into an input field. I used the code below and it worked perfectly :

```
    protected void txtBirthDate_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((TextBox)sender).Attributes.Add("placeholder", "dd/mm/yyyy");
    }
```

Here's the result for my textbox:

[image]

EDIT:

From Anant Dabhi's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27731602/how-to-add-an-attribute-to-textbox-in-extension-class/27731648#27731648) I discovered that I can simply do this :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`placeholder`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) attribute,

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
```

Here's a [Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/theonlygusti/ftc4udpd/).

**NOTE:**

This attribute only exists in HTML5, and is unsupported in IE < 10, so for IE 7, 8 and 9 see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436125/the-best-placeholder-polyfil-script-for-ie7-ie8-and-ie9), which in turn suggests [jQuery Placeholder](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder).

There is also a pure jQuery work-around, explored [here](http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html#jQuery-Fix-for-All-Browsers).

Comment: Can an input field be data bound by any way ? Something like "Text='<%# Bind("SomeField") %>'" of the textbox ?

Comment: What does data bound mean?

Comment: Meaning that if this input control is in a formview which is bound to a datasource, is there a way to bind the input control to a field of the formview datasource so that it displays the data from the database in addition to accepting input from the user for that field?

Comment: You can do that via PHP only (or your server-side scripting language), just set the placeholder/value attribute of the wanted textbox.

Answer (score 4):

In html5 there is an attribute that does that for you. It's the `placeholder` attribute.
For older browsers, you can polyfill that functionality with [placeholder.js](http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/); all you have to do is include that script in your page, and it'll work.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="my super cool placeholder text here" />
```