# How to add an attribute to textbox in extension class

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I've created an extension class for Textbox as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MyApplication.App_Code 
{
    public class DateTextBox : TextBox
    {
        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
           //this is what iwant to do :
           //((TextBox)sender).Attributes.Add("placeholder", "dd/mm/yyyy");
           base.OnPreRender(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to add a "placeholder" attribute to the textbox control on prerender, but i'm not sure about how to reference the sender textbox control.

Answer (score 3):

You just use `this`:

```
this.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "dd/mm/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 3):

The current instance is your textbox. Use `this.Attributes`?

```
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        this.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "dd/mm/yyyy");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't need sender here. your class instance itself represents the text box.

so simply use :

```
Attributes.Add("placeholder", "dd/mm/yyyy");
```

remember, `this` automatically considered. so above statement is same as :

```
this.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "dd/mm/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

An Addition on @kind.code you need to write attributes.add after

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
  // Run the OnPreRender method on the base class. 

    base.OnPreRender(e);
  // Add Attributs on textbox
    this.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "dd/mm/yyyy");
}
```

**Another Option**

I think you not need to do all this override of `Textbox`
you can write simple ..as

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" ></asp:TextBox>
```