# asp:TextBox change placeholder via .NET code behind

Tags: html, asp.net, .net

Is it possible to change textbox `placeholder` via ASP.NET code behind? If so, how?

Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TXTPassR" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" 
    placeholder="Enter password" TextMode="Password"></asp:Textbox>
```

Code behind:

```
if (Something)
{
   //Change placeholder
}
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689890/add-html5-placeholder-text-to-a-textbox-net

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`Attributes.Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.attributecollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (Something)
{
    TXTPassR.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Some Text");
}
```

> AttributeCollection.Add Method (String, String): Adds an attribute to a server control's AttributeCollection object.