# Input search field doent work properly on mobile version of responsive site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a responsive website and i have use following inline script on search input field so that it show `search` by default and when on click on the fields it will clear the text so that user can enter new text.

This works fine on desktop version but on mobile version i have to click two time so to set the focus on search field.

If i click once and try to enter it sets focus on address bar.

I am sure  script is breaking it on mobile devices.

Please advice if i can fix it or use jquery script to make it work properly

```
<div class="search-container">
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" Text="Search"  CssClass="txtSearch" runat="server" onfocus="if(this.value=='Search')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Search';" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>           
   <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" CssClass="btn-search" runat="server" Text="Search" onclick="btnSearch_Click" />
</div>
```

UPDATE

Rendered HTML code

```
<div class="search-container">

<input type="submit" class="btn-search btn" id="btnSearch" value="Go!" name="ctl00$btnSearch">

<input type="text" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Search';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Search')this.value='';" class="txtSearch" id="txtSearch" value="Search" name="ctl00$txtSearch">

 </div>
```

UPDATE:

On further troubleshoot i notice that same code works on the jsfiddle but breaks when used on asp.net website.

example

http://jsfiddle.net/M5Z9v/2/

http://fiddle.jshell.net/M5Z9v/2/show/

Comment: "I am sure script is breaking it on mobile devices." Then post your script.

Comment: It is their in the code `onfocus="if(this.value=='Search')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Search';"`

Comment: That's the only script?

Comment: This code works fine on desktop but breaks on mobile device.

Comment: could you show us the real HTML? not the asp code...

Comment: I have updated question with the code after rendering..

Comment: Try `onclick="if(this.value=='Search')this.value='';"`

Comment: @RohanKumar, I tried but i same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not use [placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823983/how-do-i-put-hint-in-a-asptextbox) attribute? This sidesteps the issue of possibly buggy inline scripts.

remove: `text="search"`, `onblur` and `onfocus` events

```
<asp:TextBox  placeholder="search"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem it still fires and writes search again and works on second click. I am not able to understand the behavior

Comment: I resolved issue by wring code like this `<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch"  placeholder="Search" CssClass="txtSearch" runat="server"  CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: Thanks, initially i kept Text="Search" their and it was not working after modifying code to above it works file. With this way i don't need script

Comment: glad to hear and thanks for accepting. I've updated my answer for future people