# In ASP.NET unable to save TextBoxes if the text is given in between ''greater than' and 'less than' symbols

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, textbox

If the text input is between 'greater Than' and 'less than' symbol, I am unable to save the text. Kindly find a solution to this either in Javascript or ASP.net

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["<" in a text box in ASP.NET --> how to allow it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146309/in-a-text-box-in-asp-net-how-to-allow-it)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Comment: Please suggest me: I need to show validation only if some text is entered in between < and >. Rest of the cases should be accepted by the browser. Suggest a solution without security concern.

Answer (score 0):

Such symbols are forbidden for security reasons - otherwise someone can simply inject their code. If you need to pass such symbols you should pass them like this : "/<" "/>" 
Or Set TextBox attribute `ValidateRequestMode = ValidateRequestMode.Disabled`

Comment: Could you suggest a way by using JavaScript to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow HTML tags i.e "<>" then you need to set validateRequest="false" in ASP pages , best thing is to parse those tags using HTML encoder .

Comment: Where we have to make validateRequest="false"?

Comment: In the aspx page , the first line , it's a attribute .

Comment: If I do that, Is there any drawback?

Comment: I tried that. But not working. I am using ASP.NET 4.5. Anything extra to be added?

Comment: Its working when I gave requestValidationMode="2.0" in httpruntime its woring
Thanks Rakesh

Comment: Could you suggest a way by using JavaScript to solve this issue?

Comment: the drawback is that , security get's compromised , you should use asp.net "Antixss" or create your own text parser to avoid user entering malicious links and javascript code along with data , google for javascript libraries