# How to localized asp:TextBox's placeholder by reading App_LocalResources file (.resx)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a controls like this :

```
<asp:TextBox  ID="txtEnrollMember" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name"  runat="server" />
```

---

If current page's culture = `"en-us"` then the placeholder = `"Please Enter Your Name"`

If current page's culture = `"zh-tw"` then the placeholder = `"請輸入你的姓名"`

---

I am searching for a long time on google. But the related solutions is very few.

I've tried the solutions like this but not work.

> [How do I put hint in a asp:textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823983/how-do-i-put-hint-in-a-asptextbox)

---

Wanted to know what would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the App_LocalResources. Read the text for specific language and set the translation e.g. from code behind:

```
txtEnrollMember.Attributes["placeholder"] = "your transaltion";
```